# Asterisk Realtime Invalid Handler Error

Tags: real-time, asterisk

I am using Asterisk 1.6.2.19 with Realtime.

As I initiate a call via the **callfile**

> Channel: SIP/1000000
> Callerid: <1000000>
> Context: local
> Extension: 20
> Priority: 1

into a certain context and extension unfortunately there occurs the error:

> Channel 'SIP/1-0000001' sent into invalid extension 's' in context 'default', but no invalid handler.

It is strange since the default context from the error message is the one which contains the switch-statement in the **extconfig.conf**:

> [general]
> static=no
> writeprotect=no
>
> [default]
> switch => Realtime/lokal@extensions

Nevertheless: The phone rings but as one answer the call the line is busy.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?
**I.e. How to initiate a call with Realtime?**

Answer (score 0):

I made an error: in the extconfig the extension is "local" but not "lokal"